# AVPlayer video is not fitting horizontal

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, avplayer

Building my first app and trying to fit the background video horizontal.

Below is the code l'm using

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "homedocapp", withExtension: "mp4")

    Player = AVPlayer.init(url: URL!)

    PlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: Player)
    PlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    PlayerLayer.frame = self.view.frame; PlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    PlayerLayer.zPosition = -1

    Player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.none

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(PlayerLayer)

    Player.play()

    view.layer.insertSublayer(PlayerLayer, at: 0)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemReachEnd(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: Player.currentItem)


}
```

[AVPlayer Horizontal display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhaow.png)

Thank you in advances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When 'viewDidLoad' is called, view still can have incorrect size. So your PlayerLayer will have incorrect size as well. Try to move your code to the 'viewDidLayoutSubviews' function:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() 
{
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // Set up your player layer instance here
}
```

Comment: Will do! Will let you know. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Work like a charm. Now when rotating horizontal getting split screen. Will upload an image shortly

Answer (score 0):

You have to resize the player with constraints when it is initialization in viewDidLoad, cause self.view.frame isn't correct then.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

[Spilt screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52MOH.jpg)

When rotating I'm getting split screen.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController  {

var Player: AVPlayer!
var PlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!



override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "homedocapp", withExtension: "mp4")

    Player = AVPlayer.init(url: URL!)

    PlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: Player)
    PlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    PlayerLayer.frame = view.layer.frame

    Player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.none


    Player.play()

    view.layer.insertSublayer(PlayerLayer, at: 0)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemReachEnd(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: Player.currentItem)


}
```

Learning the hard way